# Show chaing slider value in console

Tags: javascript, html, events, slider, addeventlistener

I have a slider and span which display the value of the changing value like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("dynamicSet");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
let update = () => output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.addEventListener('input', update);
update();
const setAmount = document.getElementById("dynamicSet").innerHTML;
console.log(setAmount);
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <p>Aantal sets: <span id="dynamicSet"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

The webpage displays the changing value which works great! However when I try to console log it, it just shows the initial value the slider is at. I am trying to push this value to a DB (with a clikc of a submit button) but I noticed the value stayed the same as in the initial when opening the page:

[image]

I need the back end value to change as well. How can do this? i thought that the even listener already took care of this..

Comment: where did you put the console.log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this, hope it will work :-)

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("dynamicSet");
var isShow = true
output.innerHTML = slider.value
update=()=>{

output.innerHTML = slider.value; 
// Display the default slider value
console.log(slider.value)
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
//let update = () => output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.addEventListener('input', update);
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <p>Aantal sets: <span id="dynamicSet"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that is very helpful I see the value change in console!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
let update = () => {
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  console.log(slider.value)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it